# Why "wear to a funeral"? Is "wear at a funeral" OK?

Tags: prepositions

I'm reading a book about the commonest mistakes foreign learners make, either in written form or while speaking. Now, some particular words are listed that give the most trouble, like this one:

> **suitable** – for (doing something) (never *to do)
>
> > Her dress was not very suitable for wearing **to** a funeral.

Why is it **to**, and would the meaning be different if I replaced it with **at**?

Comment: You could use _to, at_, or _for_, and the basic meaning would remain the same. You could even use _during_, too, although that one might sound a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition changes the focus.  "To" implies *direction* and *intention*, while "at" implies *location* and *presence*.

Given that, it may seem a little odd to focus on going *to* a funeral rather than being *at* the funeral, but there's often little logic in idiomatic expression.  "What to wear *to*" a funeral (or any event) is [simply the more common idiom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=wear%20*%20a%20funeral&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), at least at this moment in time.

Comment: Interestingly enough, that changes when we talk about it in [past tense](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wore+at+the+funeral%2Cwore+to+the+funeral&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Comment: Could you paraphrase *wearing something to the funeral* as *wearing something in preparation to the funeral*; perhaps as a relic of *wearing something towards some event*? Or would you say the phrase carries the connotation of *bring* – something like *bring this piece of clothing to the funeral*? I understand the general difference in meaning, but I'm not sure if I'm right about my intuition as to when I'd use it exactly. *To* sounds more normal, "idiomatic", while *at* sounds explicit with respect to location.

Comment: @userr2684291  I think it's just another idiom, and possibly a relatively recent one at that.  If you wear something *to* the event then you will be wearing it *at* the event, so you'd think you'd just use "at".  But that's not how people talk :/